# Modifying Google Maps WaterMark

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a Google Maps mapView in a ScrollView. it works fine, except when Scrolling I get some ugly black backgrounds along the bottom and top.

Here's a video of the issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLla7nS6Ehc&feature=youtu.be

To fix this, I wrapped the Map in a FrameLayout and made it bigger than the actual container, this fixes the issue, except now I can't see the Google watermark anymore. I tried using a bottom padding, but with the padding the black pattern shows up again, but this time only at the bottom.

Is it okay to put a TextView in the FrameLayout with the font and style of the Google Maps watermark as a work around? Am I violating the TOS if I do this?

This is the xml for my fix:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_view_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/location"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/full_margin"
    android:background="@color/transparent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/off_white"
        map:mapType="normal" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/transparent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

EDIT: Fragment code:

public class MapFragment extends Fragment
     implements View.OnClickListener,
    com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback {

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_business_home, container, false);

        final Bundle mapViewSavedInstanceState = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getBundle("mapViewSaveState") : null;

        initializeViewComponents(rootView, mapViewSavedInstanceState);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void initializeViewComponents(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        scrollView = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);

        mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());

        this.map = googleMap;

        // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        onAsyncLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onResume();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onLowMemory();
        }
        super.onLowMemory();
    }
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "SAVING TO INSTANCE STATE");

        //This MUST be done before saving any base class variables
        final Bundle mapViewSaveState = new Bundle(outState);

        if (mapView != null) { // May be null after onDestroView
            mapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewSaveState);
            outState.putBundle("mapViewSaveState", mapViewSaveState);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show the map activity/fragment?